# A site where to plot curves?

Tags: curves

I do hope you can answer this question. I know only two sitesbut on one: *Wolfram* the scale are distorted and on the other: *Online integral calculator* you can plot only onr curve.

Can you suggest some free sites where you can plot more curves in a neat way?

Please give a link to a site where it is possible to *save the images with name* in one's paint.net or other app

Comment: Have you considered [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) ?

Comment: See [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: Another site is [Sagemath cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: Plotshare (online interface to GNUPlot): http://plotshare.com/

Comment: When your are done graphing you can export it as a png-file (export function can be found in the menu in the upper right corner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycjg6qb7s5 here is site which plots curves.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/739757)

Comment: @Björn should I delete it?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, Your strictness will harm all viewers who will look for this precious info. Thanks Ramanujan, you might add another link to avoid deletion.

Comment: @tvb I don't know